# TimeSpan default value format

Tags: c#, class, timespan

I don't know how to hardcode in a time value into the timespan datatype? How do I do this? MY error below is that it will not accept '13:00' for the timespan value. Clock is the **class**. The date also will work.

Like, do I use parenthesis to make the class accept *13:00hrs* or what do I do?

```
AddTime new1 = new AddTime(23 / 01 / 2015, 13:00);
```

Comment: are you looking for something like this? `new DateTime(2015, 1, 23, 0, 13, 0);` DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds)

Comment: What is this AddTime class and what are its constructor parameters types?

Comment: DateTime and TimeSpan, but it's alright now, I've changed them to strings for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Use TimeSpan constructor to specify:
// ... Days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds.
// ... The TimeSpan returned has those values.
TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 13, 0, 0);
Console.WriteLine(span);
```

http://www.dotnetperls.com/timespan

Comment: Actually, I want to be able to hardcode in the time, into the new instance, but It will not let me.

Comment: use the Add instance method, it's in the link there

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to do this. All I need is to be able to have that line of code above to work and not give me and error when I try to use the time I want to use

Comment: @notc1 show your new code and what you're trying to accomplish because I'm confused on what you mean hardcode?

Comment: I'm working with delegates and want to be able to display this info after my msg. So i'm testing it. I want to hardcode my **test values** into the new instance to see how it gets displayed

Comment: I dont think you should be using the clock class that's for animations and takes a timeline not time span. I don't know the type of app you're working on so I cant give advice yet.

Comment: Ok 1 minute, I'm going to change the class name

Comment: That was my mistake, I don't want to use the clock class, I have my class with just a date and a time, DateTime & TimeSpan

Comment: It's alright now, to make things easier for myself, I'm changing everything to string's, just to see how it works, for now. Thanks!